# Transparent .mov video into sequence of png with transparent background ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, png, transparency, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to convert Memoji from an iPhone/Mac into series of png with transparent background so I can create a sprite sheet. When press a spacebar I can clearly see it has a transparent background, however when run `ffmpeg -i sprite/video.mov -r 24/1  sprite/output%03d.png` with ffmpeg it creates png with black background.

```
ffmpeg -i  sprite/IMG_5386.mov -b:v 16M sprite/output%03d.png
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sprite/IMG_5386.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2021-10-13T09:06:52.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.description: Memoji video, skin tone: Fair Skin Tone 3; hairstyle: Black, Short wavy bob with side parting; eyes: Brown;, facial hair: Black, Horseshoe moustache Short beard;, headgear: Denim, Baseball Cap
  Duration: 00:00:02.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2496 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x480, 2114 kb/s, 56.74 fps, 60 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-13T09:06:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : HEVC
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 66 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-13T09:06:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'sprite/output%03d.png':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    com.apple.quicktime.description: Memoji video, skin tone: Fair Skin Tone 3; hairstyle: Black, Short wavy bob with side parting; eyes: Brown;, facial hair: Black, Horseshoe moustache Short beard;, headgear: Denim, Baseball Cap
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: png, rgb24(pc, bt709, progressive), 640x480, q=2-31, 16000 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-13T09:06:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 png
frame=  179 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:02.98 bitrate=N/A speed=9.04x
video:13740kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: I've updated my question, log added.

Comment: FFmpeg currently does not support decoding of HEVC with alpha. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7965

Comment: Thank you. So it's not possible to create transparent spritesheet from Memoji video?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click your transparent `.mov` video on your Mac. `Services -> Encode Selected Video Files -> set Apple ProRes -> tick Preserve Transparency -> Continue`. Then run your command `ffmpeg -i sprite/video.mov -r 24/1  sprite/output%03d.png`. That will generate transparent pngs.